# Godaddy not decoding aspx file

Tags: asp.net, hosting, godaddy-api

I try to use C# to create a web page, and I use the visual studio as my editor. My web host is godaddy and I use the FTP in visual studio to upload all testing files successfully. When I browsing my testing site it's only shows me the original code I typed in the Visual studio. Can someone help me about that? Thanks very much.

[ This is live web result. [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y31SA.jpg)

[Here is the files I successfully uploaded to my host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s1e8.jpg)

Comment: The provider must run .net/iis in order to display aspx files. Either it is now configured for php or it does not support it.

Comment: thanks for answer the question, and I found that the godaddy cPanel does not support the asp.net, I just put my files to Plesk panel on godaddy and it looks everything works well.